# How to attach or glue metal pieces to a cloth simulation?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm new to blender and trying to attach or glue some metal pieces with a cloth simulation but I'm not able to do it correctly.

I want to attach some metal pieces with the cloth simulation. and want to show that the weight of those metal pieces are stretching the cloth object.

In the gif you can see a coat with some metal objects are attached.
[image]
[image: here you can see some basic shapes that are metal objects]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=lgrSDW2n" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/lgrSDW2n/)

Comment: parenting is working but metal pieces are behaving a little weird

Answer (score 1):

Select the metal object, shift select the cloth, switch to *Edit* mode, select 3 vertices of the cloth mesh that are close to the object and that are not aligned in a row and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> *Make Vertex Parent*:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: its not working i have tried

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=lgrSDW2n" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/lgrSDW2n/)

Comment: thank you moonboots for the help I'm able to attach metal pieces  but they are rotating or behave little weird

Comment: you can check the gif i have attached. there is a character wearing a cloth with some metal objects on it want to create something similar.

Comment: I've edited, it looks like it works better if the vertices are not aligned

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=XX6zxeBd" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/XX6zxeBd/)

Comment: thank you so much @moonboot now its working :)